# isDerivedKeyCorrect is not recognized as a function

Tags: keystore

I call lightwallet in my routes : the keystore is created whenever the user logs in (/login). Then, in another route (/newItem) I have to sign a transaction calling lightwallet.signing.signTx(keyStore, keyStorePw, data, address).

When this function is called I get this error message : 
TypeError: keystore.isDerivedKeyCorrect is not a function.

Note that I use : 
node v8.2.1
npm v5.2.0
eth-lightwallet v2.5.6
Linux 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

/!\ Beware not to call this on a serialized keystore /!\

It can trigger this error if you try to use a serialized keystore instead of the keystore object later, while calling `Lightwallet.signing.signTx` for example.